# ListView updating automatically and adding only new data items

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview in which a user adds his comments on a particular topic, these are then stored on server,
as multiple users may add comment i wish the listview to update periodically (say 10sec),
and add only the latest data and not the complete data as it will slow down the application.

How do i do this.?

Comment: @slukian I have used a custom adapter which takes takes in paramters as ArrayList<comment>

Comment: After modifying your `ArrayList<comment>`, you must call `YourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged`, which will cause the UI to reflect your changes.

Comment: yup, but by doing this the complete list will be rebuilt, isn't it ?

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as my knowledge goes, there is no other way to tell a `ListView` that it should look for more items. I would *love* to be proven wrong on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix some Buffer Comments something like 50. If the number of comments is more than 50 then display the last 50 comments only. Implement pagination concept from the server. Keep some 'Load More' button or Auto Load functionality(just like in twitter or facebook) for viewing more rows in the List.

Comment: this is an alternative method but does not answer my actual question, how do i update list periodically add only the latest data ?

Comment: Just create an Object for Timer. Schedule it for every 10 seconds or what ever the time you want to schedule. run the AsyncTask every time to fetch the data. everytime you start the AsyncTask, check the previous AsyncTask status, whether it is completed or inProgress. If still the previous on is in progress, then schedule the next AsyncTask after 10 more seconds. I hope you understand.

Comment: Ya i understood this one! thanks!!! Now only one thing that remains is how to add only those items in list, which are new rather than recreating the whole list ?

Comment: Every response will be having a specific time with seconds. Please pass the past time with in the next request from which the Server will return the comments between the time sent in the request and current time. So every request and responses will contain the time tag.

Comment: okk! thanks a lot! a bit complex method, but will do the job!

Comment: Ya i will for sure, just waiting to see if any easier way to do the same exists!